# SharePoint Moderator Cards

Tags: discussion, community, business-cards

We recently printed some business cards for our Stack Exchange employees and they turned out great.

It got us thinking: our sites' moderators have been working hard to keep our sites high quality for the past few years. They may not be employees, per se, but great community moderators are why our communities are safe, sane, and worth visiting in the first place..

If you're a moderator, would you be interested in having your own SharePoint Stack Exchange contact card? Would you find it useful?

I can see them being handy to pass out during your local SharePoint meetups or conferences.

Below is a mockup:

<sub>(click on image to see full res version)</sub>

[image: SharePoint Moderator Cards]

Of course Twitter ID/phone# are optional. It can be Skype, AIM, URL etc.

Note: the text rendering in the mockup is slightly blurry. But when printed it will be crisp.

Answer (score 2):

I was passing out these in bunches at SharePoint conference. They are of very high quality and excellent graphics. GJ jin! Recommended!